# Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 27

Tags: flutter, gridview, range, runtime-error

[image]

This is the part of the code where I use GrieView...

I am fetching a json list from an API but I keep getting this error
[image]

on the emulator, it only shows one of the products and the rest it says
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 27 ...

Please help me, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please avoid posting code-image, read [tour guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Share your code as well to get better answer.

Comment: Make sure that your product list has item in it, maybe the problem can be that you are trying to access a list that is not ready yet, because of some future api call.

Comment: I printed out product in the console and it's bringing out value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify that the variable value.products contains elements

Comment: I have the products returning value...it's an asynchronous function though...